# Get Chef/Puppet Notification in Teamcity

Tags: teamcity, chef-infra

I'm using Teamcity as my CI tool and Chef for deployment. I want to get the notification/statistics of my Chef deployment process in my Teamcity tool. Teamcity doesn't seem to have any plugins as such to achieve this task. Suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of an existing handler for Chef that sends to Teamcity, but check out the [HipChat handler](https://github.com/cwjohnston/chef-hipchat) and you'll see what to do to. Most of the provider-specific bits go in `files/default/handler.rb`, replace that with using a Teamcity API gem and you should be all set.